# Localization Laravel don't work "setLocale::"

Tags: laravel, localization, routes

I use laravel 5.3 and `setLocale` is not working

If i use `setLocate` in Route -> is not working, example:

```
Route::get('loc/{locale?}', function($locale) {
App::setLocale($locale);
return redirect()->back();});
```

But if i use this elsewhere in my file routes is working!
I mentioned in the code indicates:

```
$locale = 'en';
App::setLocale($locale);
```

Ele i use homecontroller :

```
Route::get('loc/{locale}', 'HomeController@language');
```

In file homecontroller:

```
public function language($locale)
{
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This method also do not work

Comment: Do you have an error? If not, in your controller can you show `dd(app()->getLocale())` after you set the locale?

Comment: No, i do not have error.
If i use `dd(app()->getLocale())` after `setLocate` i see - "en" or  "ru" that's what I chose, BUT my lengauge do not change in site.
If i change lang in file `app.php` -> good, my lengauge ghange

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `App::setLocale($locale)` isn't persisting your changes. So if you want a dynamic way of changing the locale you have 2 options :

1. Add the locale in the URI: `ru.example.com` or `example.com/ru`.

You can then capture the locale from the request.

2. Persist the locale for the user or the app, in a database for example.

When you hit `example.com/ru`, here's what would happen:

```
// HomeController.php
public function language($locale)
{
    // Validate locale if needed

    // Update or create the locale in settings table
    App\Setting::updateOrCreate(['name' => 'locale'], ['value' => $locale]);

    // Redirect back
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Then in your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` :

```
// App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    // Get the locale stored in the settings table
    $locale = App\Setting::where('name', 'locale')->first();

    // Setup the app locale
    app()->setLocale($locale ? $locale->value : config('app.locale'));
}
```

So your `settings` table would look like this :

```
id | name      | value
-- | --------- | ---------------
1  | locale    | ru
2  | timezone  | Europe/Brussels
3  | copyright | @2016 ACME Inc
```